# Making a soccer game on pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am having trouble to make the collision of the soccer ball. How do you get the player to move the ball? I have no idea how to do this. I attached my code that I used for the collision with the soccer ball. So far when the player runs into the ball, it just goes into a diagonal line and does not go into the net. Can anyone please help?

```
# collision scenario for what happenes when second soccer player collides with ball
    blocks_hit_list_soccer2 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(soccer_Avatar2, block_list, False)
    for i in blocks_hit_list_soccer2:
        soccer_Avatar2.rect.x -= soccer2_x_speed
        soccer_Avatar2.rect.y -= soccer2_y_speed
        soccer2_x_speed = 0
        soccer2_y_speed = 0


# collision scenario for what happens when ball collides with wall
    blocks_hit_list_ball = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(soccer_Ball, block_list, False)
    for i in blocks_hit_list_ball:
        soccer_Ball.rect.x == ball_x_speed
        soccer_Ball.rect.y == ball_y_speed
        ball_x_speed = 0
        ball_y_speed = 0


# collision scenario for what happens when ball collides with first soccer player
    blocks_hit_list_ball = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(soccer_Ball, player1_list, False)
    for i in blocks_hit_list_ball:
        soccer_Ball.rect.x += ball_x_speed
        soccer_Ball.rect.y += ball_y_speed
        ball_x_speed = 5
        ball_y_speed = 5


# collision scenario for what happens when ball collides with second soccer player
    blocks_hit_list_ball2 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(soccer_Ball, player2_list, False)
    for i in blocks_hit_list_ball2:
        soccer_Ball.rect.x -= ball_x_speed
        soccer_Ball.rect.y -= ball_y_speed
        ball_x_speed = 5
        ball_y_speed = 5
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. You have to attempt to solve the problem on your own before you ask for help here, especially since this is a homework assignment. It's also not really clear how your game should work. Please add a more detailed description of the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an image for the soccer ball, then this code will work! The following makes the soccer ball (or image) move when the User touches the Left or Right side of their device's screen.....

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int buffer = lp.leftMargin;
            if( x < screenWidth-buffer ) {
                int ScreenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                float Xtouch = event.getRawX();
                int sign = Xtouch > 0.5*ScreenWidth ? 1 : -1;
                float XToMove = 60; // or whatever amount you want
                int durationMs = 50;
                v.animate().translationXBy(sign*XToMove).setDuration(durationMs);
            }else {
                if( x < ( screenWidth/2) ) {
                    int ScreenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                    float xtouch = event.getRawX();
                    int sign = xtouch < 0.5 / ScreenWidth ? 1 : -1;
                    float xToMove = 60; // or whatever amount you want
                    int durationMs = 50;
                    v.animate().translationXBy(sign*xToMove).setDuration(durationMs);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you!! but unfortunately that didn't work for my code :(

Comment: Oh...well i hope you find the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one more thing.....

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int buffer = lp.leftMargin;
            if( x > ( screenWidth/2) ) {
                int ScreenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                float Xtouch = event.getRawX();
                int sign = Xtouch > 0.5*ScreenWidth ? 1 : -1;
                float XToMove = 60; // or whatever amount you want
                int durationMs = 50;
                v.animate().translationXBy(sign*XToMove).setDuration(durationMs);
            }else {
                if( x < ( screenWidth/2) ) {
                    int ScreenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                    float xtouch = event.getRawX();
                    int sign = xtouch < 0.5 / ScreenWidth ? 1 : -1;
                    float xToMove = 60; // or whatever amount you want
                    int durationMs = 50;
                    v.animate().translationXBy(sign*xToMove).setDuration(durationMs);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```